# Tabulator Ajax Sorting - Passing field as sorters[0][field] and sorters[0][dir] , how can i change this to custom parameter

Tags: tabulator

Ajax sorting is working in Tabulator . but the format of field passing to the server is sorters[0][field]. I want to change this to custom field .

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
ajaxRequesting : function (url, params, response) {
        if (params.sorters.length > 0) {
          params.sort = params.sorters[0]['field'];
          params.order = params.sorters[0]['dir'];
        }
        return params;
    },
```

Comment: Please explain what the code does and how it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Tabulator 5 you can alter the sorting parameters with custom config parameter during Tabulator creation `ajaxURLGenerator: alterAjaxParams`.

For example:

```
function alterAjaxParams(url, config, params) {
    if (url) {
        if (params && Object.keys(params).length) {
            if (!config.method || config.method.toLowerCase() == "get") {
                config.method = "get"
                url += (url.includes("?") ? "&" : "?") + processParams(params)
            }
        }
    }
    return url
}

function processParams(params) {
    let output = [];
    for (var key in params) {
        let v = params[key]
        if (Array.isArray(v)) {
            // Array value.
            v.forEach(function(item) {
                if (key == 'sort') {
                    // Sort param customisation.
                    output.push({key: key, value: item.field + "," + item.dir})
                }
                else if (key == 'filter') {
                    // Filter param customisation.
                    output.push({key: key, value: item.field + "_" + item.type + "_" + item.value})
                }
                else {
                    output.push({key: key, value: v})
                }
            })
        }
        else if (typeof(v) === "object") {
            // Object value.
            for (var key in v) {
                output.push({key: key, value: v})
            }
        }
        else {
            // String value.
            output.push({key: key, value: v})
        }
    }
    let encoded = []
    output.forEach(function(item) {
        encoded.push(item.key + "=" + item.value)
    })
    return encoded.join("&")
}
```

The example above generates sort parameters, acceptable for Spring Pageable binding.